# Flow for authentication when MFA required for user in AWS Cognito

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

I am attempting to add MFA for user authentication to an already existing solution (built in Angular) for device management within AWS Cognito.

I am having trouble figuring out how to handle this particular response well from a user-experience perspective. It actually feels broken, so would love if anyone else has experience pain points here.

See [Use Case 23.](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js) for example implementation, mine is below:

```
authenticate(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {

    // init cognitoUser here

    return new Observable((observer) => {
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: (result: any) => {},
            onFailure: (err: Error) => {},
            mfaRequired: (codeDeliveryDetails: any) => {

                // SMS has just been sent automatically 
                // and it needs to be confirmed within this scope

                // The example linked requests the code via `confirm()`
                // which is awful UX...and since this is a service
                // probably non-compliant with best practice
                // However, without this `confirm` at this point in                     
                // time, we have no confirmationCode below

                cognitoUser.sendMFACode(confirmationCode, {
                    onSuccess: (result) => {
                        observer.next(result);
                        observer.complete();
                    }, onFailure: (err: Error) => {
                        observer.error(err);
                        observer.complete();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Expected:

- If the user authenticates successfully but has not added this device through MFA, we can manage the redirect to appropriate confirmation code form page and trigger the `sendMFACode` function manually (perhaps through some sort of limited session?)

Issue/s:

- we don't have a session, so we have no way of asking the user the MFA code sent automatically outside of this login screen...catch 22?
- adding another show/hide field in the login form doesn't work as it would hit the `sendMfaCode` function multiple times, resulting in multiple SMS codes sent.

Has anyone had any luck stepping out of this flow?

Comment: This apparently is the intended usage, however they understand the UX issue and it has been flagged a new feature request - https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/382

Comment: As it stands, AWS do not seem to be taking this issue seriously. I would say for people coming here looking to implement Cognito with MFA, be prepared to roll your entire stack as React to perhaps have at least some control over user experience or use another auth service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whilst I’m sure very talented people worked on the **amazon-cognito-identity-js** API, it is just straight up badly designed. Thus why it’s been depricated. My personal advise would be to migrate to **Amplify**, which makes me much less angry.

With **Amplify** you can do these ones.

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify'
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth'

let mfaRequired = false

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        userPoolWebClientId: '',
        userPoolId: ''
    }
})

const logUserIn = (user) => {
  // Go forth and be happy
}

// Run me on your login form's submit event
const login = async (username, password) => {
  const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password)

  if (user.challengeName === 'SMS_MFA') {
    // Change UI to show MFA Code input
    mfaRequired = true
    return
  }
  return logUserIn(user)
}

// Run me when the user submits theire MFA code
const senfMfaCode = async (mfaCode) => {
  const user = await Auth.confirmSignIn(mfaCode)
  return logUserIn(user)
}
```

BUT if for some sad reason you need to keep using **amazon-cognito-identity-js** don’t worry. I got you.

Just keep the `cognitoUser` object stored outside the callback. The documentation is a little misleading because it only show’s self contained examples but there’s no reason that you can’t notify your UI when MFA is required and then call `cognitoUser.sendMFACode()` later.

Just remember that the documentation show’s the passing of `this` to `sendMFACode()` for scoping (which is terrible) but you can just declare your callbacks as a variable and share it between your `authenticateUser()` and `sendMFACode()` functions (or as many functions as you like).

```
import { CognitoUserPool, AuthenticationDetails, CognitoUser } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'

export let mfaRequired = false
export let cognitoUser = null

export const cognitoCallbacks = {
  mfaRequired () {
    // Implement you functionality to show UI for MFA form
    mfaRequired = true
  },
  onSuccess (response) {
    // Dance for joy the code gods be glorious.
  },
  onFailure () {
    // Cry.
  }
}

export const logUserIn = payload => {
  cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
    Username: 'Matt Damon',
    Pool: new CognitoUserPool({
      UserPoolId: '',
      ClientId: ''
    })
  })
  return cognitoUser.authenticateUser(new AuthenticationDetails(payload), cognitoCallbacks)
}

export const sendMfaCode = MFACode => {
  cognitoUser.sendMFACode(MFACode, cognitoCallbacks)
}
```

That’s a super basic implementation and on top of that you could,

1. Just overwrite the `mfaRequired` function in an external module to do whatever you want.
2. Wrap the whole thing in a pub/sub plugin and subscribe to events.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is great, thanks so much @stwilz! What a legend. I'll give it a go over the weekend. Appreciate the details response.

Comment: All good man. I drafted that code up on the fly so if you need a working example I can link through a JSFiddle.

Comment: I am trying something similar but with TOTP (not SMS) and the hosted UI. When I sign up using hosted UI, it should show or respond back with the secret key for the TOTP setup but I don't see any secret key either displayed in the screen or in the ajax responses. What am I missing here?

Comment: I have selected the MFA as optinal. So for some users MFA is not received while SignUp. How can I trigger this using aws-amplify-react-native

Comment: Be careful with this! If the `cognitoUser` object is stored in a backend variable, it will be overwritten by another user who logs in at almost the same time. So you might call `sendMFACode` on the wrong user!

Comment: @Jan are you able to supply a gist your implementation that demonstrates how the wrong user is called?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I thought this answer might be helpful for anyone who is still using the `amazon-cognito-identity-js` API instead of Amplify. @stwilz's answer works somewhat, but there are a few complications that come when you stray too far away from the documentation's use cases (and might come about when doing TOTP MFA instead of SMS MFA). I've created a workaround to address situations where you might get errors like `Invalid Access Token`, `Missing parameter Session`, or `Invalid session for the user`.

If you need to use something like `sendMFACode`outside of the callbacks, it's not enough to just keep `cognitoUser` stored outside the callback. You actually have to call the `authenticateUser` function *again*, then call the sendMFACode within the callback. It gets more complicated with `verifySoftwareToken` for TOTP, where you actually have to store the Cognito user object and then reassign it when calling `authenticateUser` again.

If none of this makes sense, I've created a simple Github Gist that uses React and `amazon-cognito-identity-js` to show how such a flow would work. It's here: https://gist.github.com/harve27/807597824720d0919476c0262e30f587